# When will Starfinder become an available tag?

Tags: support, tags

[Starfinder](https://paizo.com/starfinder) is now released but I notice there is still no tag for it.  I cannot make one yet, but are there plans for someone else to?

Answer (score 13):

Tags only exist when they're on a question, so a Starfinder tag can't be made until we have a Starfinder question. (Since tags don't exist without questions, we also don't *need* a Starfinder tag until we have at least one question about it.)

If you want to ask a question and the appropriate tag isn't available, just ask it, then leave a comment asking someone to make the tag. Someone who has the account privileges (anyone with 300+ rep) for tag creation will take care of it.