# Should we create a "Tormenta" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tormenta RPG is a very popular game on Brazil, with many expansions, there's two main systems, one based on 3.5 D&D and other based on Pathfinder, many brazilian players speak english and search for answers in this language, mainly for GM techniques, i think a Tormenta (or TormentaRPG) tag would be relevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer shamlessly ripped wholesale from [d7's answer to a similar question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7425/15469):

Tags only exist when they're on a question, so a Tormenta tag can't be made until we have a Tormenta question. (Since tags don't exist without questions, we also don't *need* a Tormenta tag until we have at least one question about it.)

If you want to ask a question and the appropriate tag isn't available, just ask it, then leave a comment asking someone to make the tag. Someone who has the account privileges (anyone with 300+ rep) for tag creation will take care of it.

Comment: Right, i thought the process could be reverse, to bring Tormenta players to the community, but the actual logic makes way more sense